# Compiling stops working as soon as more than one entry is made in .bib file

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I have a report which I am writing and want to use bibtex for my referencning. I did this as follows:

```
\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

My ref.bib looks like this:

```
@misc{aci,
author = {ACI Chemicals},
   institution = {ACI Chemicals},
   title = {Ballistic Separator},
   year = {2017}
}
```

Inline I then cite it using

```
\cite{aci}
```

This works fine and the reference is shown. However as soon as I add a second reference in my ref.bib file it stops working. Here is an example:

```
@misc{aci,
   author = {ACI Chemicals},
   institution = {ACI Chemicals},
   title = {Ballistic Separator},
   year = {2017}
   }

@misc{bmk,
   author = {BMI für Umwelt},
   title = {Sortierung und Recycling von Kunststoffabfällen in Österreich},
   institution = {BMK},
   year = {2019}
}
```

Now I can neither use `\cite{aci}` or `\cite{bmk}` because neither of them work. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Do not show chunks of code, but a minimal working example (MWE) so we can test "as is" if the document produce that and in this case, search for a  solution. BTW,  have you clean all the auxiliar files before compiling and without forget run bibtex ?

Comment: we can not debug "because neither of them work" what error do you get? have you run bibtex again?